# Выполнение скрипта изменения <div> страницы после перехода по ссылке

Tags: javascript

Задача, с одной стороны, простая: поменять стили отображения на странице.
Проще говоря, один  поменять на другой .

В рамках одной страницы сделать это не проблема (через закрытие и отображение стилей):

```
<div id="old" class="flex">
    содержание
</div>

<div id="new" class="flex_new" style="display: none">
    содержание
</div>

<a href="#" class="link" onclick="newDivHere()">Смена стиля</a>

function newDivHere() {
    document.getElementById("old").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("new").style.display="flex";
}
```

И это работает, если я нахожусь на данной странице.

Но как перекроить скрипт, чтобы при заходе на эту страницу (используя кнопку перехода), осуществлялась смена стиля?

`<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="link" onclick="newDivHere()">Смена стиля</a>`

При таком варианте, разумеется, сначала меняется стиль, после осуществляется переход.

Задача: сделать наоборот - переход -> смена стиля.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь к ссылке параметр

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>?newstyle=true" class="link">Смена стиля</a>
```

И при загрузке новой странице проверяй наличие параметра в урле, после чего выполняй скрипт.

```
let url = new URL(window.location.href);

if (url.searchParams.get('newstyle')) {
    document.getElementById("oldDiv").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("newDiv").style.display="flex";
};
```

То же самое можно сделать через hash в url

Если нужно чтобы запомнился стиль - можно его так же складывать в localstorage, и при загрузке каждой новой странице читать что там есть в локалсторейдже и выполнять относительно этого скрипт.

Comment: Не хочет. 
Может быть я что то делаю не так.

Редирект происходит с параметром ?newstyle. На нужную страницу перехожу, но стили не меняются.

Скрипт проверки кидал на страницу перехода через <script> </script>.
Равно как и пробовал его в функцию онклика (newDivHere) запихнуть от безнадежности :)

Comment: онклик ни при чем. забудьте про него в данном случаи. Вы открыли какую-то страницу сайта с параметром. в js у вас скрипт стоит, который смотрит, есть ли какие-то параметры у страницы. АГА, есть нужный параметр. и тогда выполняется все что внутри. Т.е., вы там запускаете нужную функцию

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. Однако, работать отказывается при таком виде:
`<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>?newstyle" class="link" onclick="newDivHere()">Смена стиля</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
url = new URL(window.location.href);
 if (url.searchParams.get('newstyle')) {

function newDivHere2() {
document.getElementById("oldDiv").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("newDiv").style.display="flex";

};
  console.log('запустить скрипт')
}
</script>`

Comment: отредактировал. Не забудьте, что <script> Должен быть ниже ваших дивов которые вы ищите в нем.

Comment: Спасибо! Так работает

Comment: если не сложно - пометьте ответ как верный пожалуйста)